# Artifactory not returning the same file with Chrome or Java Url connection

Tags: java, maven, user-agent, artifactory, urlconnection

I wrote a small piece of code to download the maven-metadata.xml file from an artifactory repository.

It is as simple as

```
URLConnection c = new URL("http://...").openConnection();
InputStream is = c.getInputStream()
```

InputStream which I then use to create an XML Document object.
When doing this, I get the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>be.comp.mapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapp3.service.universemanager</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.0-20150810.155925-225</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20150811130209</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

which is actually incomplete, compared to the file I get using the exact same URL in Google Chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>be.comp.mapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapp3.service.universemanager</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.0-20150810.155925-225</version>
  <versioning>
    <snapshot>
      <timestamp>20150812.135251</timestamp>
      <buildNumber>231</buildNumber>
    </snapshot>
    <lastUpdated>20150812135517</lastUpdated>
    <snapshotVersions>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>test-sources</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>pom</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
      <snapshotVersion>
        <extension>jar</extension>
        <value>1.0.0.0-20150812.135251-231</value>
        <updated>20150812135251</updated>
      </snapshotVersion>
    </snapshotVersions>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

I tried to solve this by setting the user agent of the URLConnection or to differently configure the Artifactory repo but couldn't solve this wierd issue up to know.

Comment: It looks like you are getting older version when accessing Artifactory via Java URL connection, are you sure that the requests are identical? Chrome may be sending cookies that you don't see...

Comment: In addition chrome might be caching an older response

Comment: Also, is it possible that chrome is performing authentication? try using curl for the same request

Comment: I tried with IE and Firefox, of which I had reset the cach/coockies/etc and I got the right file. The version I get with artifactory is the right one, the one with Java not. The URL are exactly the same.. So I have really no idea

Comment: Check the Artifactory access.log, make sure that both requests (Java, browser) have the same path and same user

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering same problem. They seem to have some logic based on the User Agent. So if you send User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_251, like in URLConnection by default then it will give you part of the content. If you send any other UserAgent, then it is fine:

```
URLConnection hc = new URL(url).openConnection();
hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "myJavaCode");
return hc.getInputStream()
```